# Can't find php.ini file 5.4.19 version in Windows 2003 server install

Tags: php

We have php 5.4.19 installed.  PHP is installed in c:\php.  There is a php.ini-development file and a php.ini-production file there.  However, there is no php.ini file there.  If I run phpinfo() it says:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\WINDOWS
```

However, I don't see a php.ini file in c:\windows either.

Where the heck is the php.ini file.  I know I have found this file before and modified it and I remember it being difficult to find.  However, I can't for the life of me find it now.

Oh, the Microsoft search CANNOT find a file named php.ini either.
I tried installing the voidtools and it doesn't find a file named php.ini either.
I tried changing php.ini-production but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Use the search engine of windows and maybe try to set in windows explorer to show hidden files. Just a hint though..

Comment: Alternatively, this `MFT` search engine finds files extremely fast: http://www.voidtools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration path isn't important.  The next line down should tell you what the loaded configuration file is.  I suspect it says "none".

It's possible to run PHP without a configuration file.  I don't recommend it.  Create a php.ini.  After installing PHP, you're supposed to copy either the development or production file to php.ini in the same path, and modify from there.

Comment: Ok, I could have SWORE we had this file because we had to make changes before.  However, renaming the changes we are making in the php.ini-production file and renaming it php.ini does show "SOME" of the changes are now making it. PDO is still not working but that appears to be a different question as this point on a different thread.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you dont have file on path c:/php/php.ini and then php try load in windows diretcory maybe you can try create file on c:/php/php.ini if not exists.
P.S sorry for my english